# How can I check the remaining disk quota?

Tags: hard-drive, quota

df does only reports the disk free space. How can I get my allowed free space?

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/94368/understanding-quota-output

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Take a look at the quota command here:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/quota

---

**quota**

For example:

quota -u user1

System response:

```
Disk quotas for user user1 (uid 501):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace files   quota   limit  grace    
     /dev/hda6     992   50000   55000              71   10000   11000
```

---

**quota report**

Report on all users over quota limits:

quota -q

Quota summary report:

repquota -a

```
Report for user quotas on device /dev/hda5
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                    Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
root      -- 4335200       0       0         181502     0     0
bin       --   15644       0       0            101     0     0
...
user1     --    1944       0       0            120     0     0
```

No limits shown with this user as limits are set to 0.

Comment: Is there a way to print in megabytes or gigabytes instead of bytes?

Comment: @becko Try 'quota -s'

Answer (score 10):

If quotas are set, "quota" command shows the details.

```
quota -v
```

Comment: Nothing returns by `quota` command through SSH. Does it mean it was not set?

Comment: @Ahmad There can still be a quota system active that doesn't use the interface `quota` is using. (I previously gave the example of cephfs here but I just see that the ceph cluster I've user access to doesn't have the `quota` command installed so it could be simply that.)

Answer (score 1):

try this command

```
repquota -sa | grep -v "0       0"
```

This will give details report for all user-driven accounts like:

```
/home]# repquota -sa | grep -v "0       0"
*** Report for user quotas on device /dev/root
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
usera      --  20018M    977G    977G           351k     0     0
userb      --  11301M  55000M  55000M           106k     0     0
users      --   35192   1000M   1000M           2092     0     0
```